# Yargs help not displaying all the help options

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I am using **yargs** to add command line options for the arguments passed to the script. When i issue the help command along with the script name, It does not display the help for **add** parameter.

```
const yargs=require('yargs');
 const argv= yargs.command('add', 'ADD A NOTE TO A FILE', {
    title : {
        describe : 'title of the file',
        demand: 'true'
    }
})
.help()
.argv;




root# node mainFile_node.js --help
Options:
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]
  --version  Show version number

     node mainFile_node.js add
YARGS ARGV:-{ _: [ 'add' ], '$0': 'mainFile_node.js' }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const yargs = require("yargs");

yargs.command({
  command: "add",
  describe: "Add new note",
  builder: {
    title: {
      // describe: 'note title',
      demandOption: true,
      type: "string"
    }
  },
  handler: function(argv) {
    console.log("My title: " + argv.title);
  }
});

yargs.parse();
```

Then run in the command line:

```sh
node filename.js add --title="title name"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add **yargs.parse()**; to the end of the file for yargs to use its pre-defined args such as --help, --version. [image]

Comment: Please prefer copy and pasting code/terminal output instead of screenshot (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
const yargs = require("yargs")
yargs.command({
  command: 'add',
  describe: 'ADD A NOTE TO A FILE',
  handler: function(){
    console.log('Adding to a file')
  }
})
```

Then execute with the below command

```
root# node mainFile_node.js --help
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const yargs=require('yargs');
const argv= yargs.command('add', 'ADD A NOTE TO A FILE', {
    title : {
        describe : 'title of the file',
        demand: 'true'
    }
}).parse()
```

u have to add the parse() method at the end. parse() will also execute the handler function if u are happen to use in the future.

or under the code

```
console.log(yargs.argv)
```

this method is useful if you did not write any code on your file but you are working on command line. let's say

node app.js add --title="somthing"   --help

in order to see the help menu u have to type `console.log(yargs.argv)`  on the file.

Answer (score 0):

First check if node ./main.js --h is working?

Then, just run node ./app.js --help on a seperate js file and then it will start working on the previous file.

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const yargs = require('yargs');

//Create add command
yargs.command({
    command:'add',
    describe:'Add a new note',
    handler:function(){
        console.log("add a new note");
    }
})

//Create remove command
yargs.command({
    command:'remove',
    describe:'Remove the note',
    handler:function(){
        console.log("Removing a note");
    }
})

//Create list command
yargs.command({
    command:'list',
    describe:'List all the notes',
    handler:function(){
        console.log("List notes");
    }
})

//Create read command
yargs.command({
    command:'read',
    describe:'read note',
    handler:function(){
        console.log("read a note");
    }
})


console.log(yargs.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yargs.command({
command: 'add',

showInHelp: true, //add this line here!!!

describe: 'add a note',
builder: {
    title: {
        describe: 'title of my note',
        demandOption: true,
        type: 'string',
        
        
    },
    body: {
        describe: 'body note',
        demandOption: true,
        type: 'string',
        

        
    }
},

handler: function (argv) {
    console.log(argv.title,'\n', argv.body, '\n creating the note', argv)
}
})
```