# Yargs help not display properly while --h is working

Tags: javascript, yargs

In my CLI when I call `node cli.js --help` I get this:

```
Options:
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
```

However, when I call `node cli.js --h` i get the expected output:

```
cli.js

Run a set of user flows and save the result

Commands:
  cli.js init     Setup .user-flowrc.json
  ...

Options:
      --version           Show version number                          [boolean]
  -v, --verbose           Run with verbose logging                     [boolean]
  ...
  -h, --help              Show help                                    [boolean]

Examples:
  init  Setup user-flows over prompts
```

I have tried to add `yargs.parse()` [Yargs help not displaying all the help options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57316466/12263245), but it did not change anything.

And I am using `.argv` at the end so it should only be called once if I understood [Why are commands missing from this yargs script help page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68051884/12263245).

Similarly i have read [yargs example - yargs/docs/examples.md](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/main/docs/examples.md) and added the alias which is why the `--h` is working.

There is the code I think is relevant:

```js
export function setupYargs(
  commands: YargsCommandObject[],
  options: { [key: string]: Options },
  config: Record<string, any> = {}
) {
  yargs.options(options)
    .parserConfiguration({ 'boolean-negation': true })
    .recommendCommands()
    .config(config)
    .example([
      ['init', 'Setup user-flows over prompts']
    ])
    .help();

  commands.forEach((command) => yargs.command(
    command.command,
    command.description,
    command?.builder || (() => {
    }),
    command.module.handler
  ));

  return yargs.argv;
}
```

If there is any other section of the code base which may be useful let me know and I will add it to the question.

--- Edit ---
I have now narrowed down the issue to the setup of the CLI.

```
const {collect, persist, assert} = readRcConfig(getRcParam());

(async () => runCli({ commands: commands, options: {
    ...GLOBAL_OPTIONS
  }, config: {...collect, ...persist, ...assert} }))();
```

Where `getRcParam()` gets the path to the configuration:

```
export function get(): string {
  // we don't rely on yargs option normalization features as this can happen before cli bootstrap
  const {rcPath, p, ["rc-path"]: rc_path } =  argv as any as ArgvOption<any>;
  const pathToCfgRc = rcPath || rc_path || p;
  return (pathToCfgRc as any as string) || join(DEFAULT_RC_PATH, DEFAULT_RC_NAME);
}
```

And is passed as a config option.